# How to keep comboBox open while selecting items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form custom comboBox that I'm hosting in a dataGridView. I can't figure out how to keep the drop down list open while the user selects items. There is no closing event to hook off of. Does anyone know how this is accomplished? I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance,
-DA

Comment: can't you use [ListBox](http://www.dotnetperls.com/listbox)?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the combobox to remain expanded even when it does not have focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GetComboBoxInfo` to get the `Handle` of the `DropDownList` and use custom `NativeWindow` to hook into the message loop of the `DropDownList` to catch some relevant message and achieve what you want. Here is the complete code of the custom `ComboBox`, it has the property `HideDropDownAfterSelect` with default value of `true`, it acts like the standard `ComboBox` by default, to make it work as you want, just set `HideDropDownAfterSelect = false`:

```
//Must add using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class Win32 {
   [DllImport("user32")]
   public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hwnd, 
                                             out Win32.COMBOBOXINFO info);
   public struct RECT {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
   }
   public struct COMBOBOXINFO {
            public int size;
            public RECT item;
            public RECT button;
            public int state;
            public IntPtr comboHwnd;
            public IntPtr itemHwnd;
            public IntPtr listHwnd;
   }
}
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox {
   NativeDropDownList dropDown = new NativeDropDownList();
   IntPtr dropDownHandle;
   bool hideDropDownAfterSelect = true;
   public CustomComboBox() {
      dropDown.ParentControl = this;
      HandleCreated += (s, e) => {
         Win32.COMBOBOXINFO info = new Win32.COMBOBOXINFO();
         info.size = Marshal.SizeOf(info);                   
         Win32.GetComboBoxInfo(Handle, out info);
         dropDownHandle = info.listHwnd;                    
      };
   }
   public bool HideDropDownAfterSelect {
      get {
         return hideDropDownAfterSelect;
      }
      set {
         if (hideDropDownAfterSelect != value) {
           hideDropDownAfterSelect = value;
           if (!value) dropDown.AssignHandle(dropDownHandle);
           else dropDown.ReleaseHandle();
         }
      }
   }
   private class NativeDropDownList : NativeWindow {
      public ComboBox ParentControl;
      protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
         if (m.Msg == 0x202) { //WM_LBUTTONUP                                    
            AcceptSelection(false);
            return;
         }
         //WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
         if (m.Msg == 0x203) AcceptSelection(true);
         base.WndProc(ref m);
      }
      private void AcceptSelection(bool hideDropDown) {
         //LB_GETCURSEL = 0x188
         Message m = Message.Create(Handle, 0x188, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
         WndProc(ref m);
         int i = m.Result.ToInt32();
         typeof(ComboBox).GetMethod("OnSelectedIndexChanged", 
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                         .Invoke(ParentControl, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
         if (i == -1) return;
         ParentControl.Text = ParentControl.Items[i].ToString();
         ParentControl.SelectAll();
         ParentControl.Invalidate();
         if (hideDropDown) {
            ParentControl.DroppedDown = false;
         }
      }
   }
} 
//Usage
customComboBox1.HideDropDownAfterSelect = false;
//You can select the item and hide the drop down by double-clicking left mouse
//It works that way because of the code above at WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
```

Comment: Great, but needs a little finessing: In the constructor, in the HandleCreated delegate, you need to add

`if (!hideDropDownAfterSelect)
 dropDown.AssignHandle(dropDownHandle);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListBox` instead of a `ComboBox`. What you want to do keep a ComboBox open even after the user has selected a choice would be unusual and unexpected behavior.

Comment: lots of reasons ... multiple selection for example.