# c# combobox prevents to close when I select and set the front text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want have a combobox with checkbox in winform ( c# ).
Firstly I tried [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and) from code Project. working is fine but when i set the around 4000 data. the performance is very slow. I do not think to set 4,000 data is good however our client wants.

So Secondly I  tired [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18929/An-OwnerDraw-ComboBox-with-CheckBoxes-in-the-Drop) from code project. But I faced two problems.

1. The combobox closes when I select item. I want to prevent it.
2. I want to show a text what user selected. e.g. If I selected two items of 10 items. I want to show the text "One Two".

What I did.

1. I spend a few hours to search but I could not get have any idea...
2. I put the property into my custom combobox.

   ```
       public string SelectedItemsText{
       get {
           string text = "";
           for (int i =0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
           {
               CheckComboBoxItem item = this.Items[i] as CheckComboBoxItem;
               if (item.CheckState)
                   text += item.Text + " ";

           }
           return text;
       }
   }
   ```

then, I call this method in toString method in my Item class.

```
 public class CheckComboBoxItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// C'tor - creates a CheckComboBoxItem
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Label of the check box in the drop down list</param>
    /// <param name="initialCheckState">Initial value for the check box (true=checked)</param>
    public CheckComboBoxItem( string text, bool initialCheckState, CheckComboBox parent )
    {
        _checkState = initialCheckState;
        _text = text;
        _parent = parent;
    }
    private CheckComboBox _parent;
    private bool _checkState = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the check value (true=checked)
    /// </summary>
    public bool CheckState
    {
        get { return _checkState; }
        set { _checkState = value; }
    }

    private string _text = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the label of the check box
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }

    private object _tag = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// User defined data
    /// </summary>
    public object Tag
    {
        get { return _tag; }
        set { _tag = value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to keep the edit control portion of the combo box consistent
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _parent.SelectedItemsText;
        //return "Select Options";
    }

}
```

But it does not work.
Could you help me please ?

Thank you for any helps.

Comment: For prevent from closing combobox, try  `checkComboBox1.DroppedDown = true;` at the end of State Changed event, is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you for help! It is very close what I want. I tried your advice and It is better. However when I scroll bottom of the item list in conbobox and then selected one, I lost position in the list. I want to keep position of the list when I select an item in the list.:(

Comment: Also I have just found the information. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673026/how-to-keep-combobox-open-while-selecting-items)
But it does not work....

Comment: @TakeoNishioka Why not just using listbox?

Comment: @Berkay
Finally, I have made custom  CheckedListBox . and it worked. Thank you!