# How can I do a hittest on a ComboBox's list and stop the list from closing when the mouse clicks on an item?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-4.8

I'm working on building a new custom control using a ComboBox control to handle the list that pops up under my other controls making the usercontrol up.

I would like to try and catch the event of clicking on a list item, and if it's in a specific area (something like e.Location.X < 20) then do something in my code and also STOP the list from closing.

Is it possible to do some type of hittest like that?  Also, is it possible to stop the list in a ComboBox from closing by somehow intercepting the click?

Comment: You can build a Custom Control, use `GetComboBoxInfo()` to get the handle of the ListControl, assign it to a `NativeWindow`, so you can override WndProc and receive messages directed to the ListControl. You can then trap `WM_LBUTTONUP`: if you don't call `base`, the list won't close if you click an item, but you can close it using the Combo's Button. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` gives you the coordinates of the mouse pointer. `LB_GETCURSEL`  / `LB_SETCURSEL`  the current Item's index (`m.Result.ToInt32()`)

Comment: ≈ https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692181/14171304

Comment: Thanks for the great info @Jimi, I have spent a lot of time on the project and ended up going with the `WM_LBTRACKPOINT` message to get my click point in the list and it's working well.  I have been struggling with dealing with the `WM_COMMAND` event though.  For my purposes dealing with it is important.  I'm trying to convert the `wParam` (low word) to a window handle of the list on the combobox then comparing it to the message params.  The first part of your comment seems like it's exactly what I'm currently after.

Comment: `WM_LBTRACKPOINT` is sent to the Owner when a ListBox has the `LBS_NOTIFY` style set. I suggested to handle the messages directed to the **ListControl** directly, using a standard [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow) object (to which you assign the Handle of the ComboBox's ListControl, retrieved calling `GetComboBoxInfo()`)

Comment: @Jimi I think you misunderstood me.  I was telling you what I did after I posted the question.  Later when reviewing your comment I was saying that the first part of your comment is exactly what I was after and needed to do.  Thanks again.